# Why cannot use ServiceWorker in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: uwp, progressive-web-apps

I have created an UWP-app with Microsoft-VisualStudio 2017. In the XAML-Code of file "Browse.xaml" I have defined a `Browser-Control` with the XAML-tag "`WebView`".

I want to realize offline caching. 
Therefore I need a `ServiceWorker`.
I navigate the WebView-Control to a WebApplication:

```
myWebBrowse.Navigate(target);
```

The JavaScript-Code in this WebApplication returns false:

```
"if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)"
```

I need the `ServiceWorker` for Offline-caching. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `WebView` in UWP shares the kernel with the Edge browser, which implements most of the browser's functions, but ServiceWorker does not.

Every time you create an instance of WebView, it is equivalent to opening a new browser, local records will not be saved.

You can create a **Progressive Web App** or **Hosted Web App** that wraps your PWA web page into a UWP app and implements some of the WinRT APIs.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and found the solution and updated the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833589/10224384).

Common constraints while developing PWA-UWP:

- Min Windows 10 Version: 1809 (Service Worker supported since for EdgeHTML WebView)
- Install SSL certificate on client devices (In case of self signed)
- App URL must start with: `https://<DomainName>` (IP address does not work)
- Client devices must have Developer Mode enabled (must allow Developer Mode / Sideloaded apps)